# Having a struct instance in more than one vector in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm building an application in Rust that backs up docker volumes.

I wanted to know which containers are using the target volume.

This is the code I use:

```
let volume = await!(get_volume_by_name(&docker, &volume_name));
let container_details = await!(get_container_details(&docker));
let mut connected_containers = Vec::new();

for container_detail in container_details {
    for mount in container_detail.mounts {
        if mount.destination == volume.mountpoint {
            connected_containers.push(container_detail);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to put all matching containers in a vector. The error that I get is:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `container_detail`
  --> src/main.rs:32:43
   |
29 |     for container_detail in container_details {
   |         ---------------- move occurs because `container_detail` has type `shiplift::rep::ContainerDetails`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
32 |                 connected_containers.push(container_detail);
   |                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
```

I know that you can't have the same value in 2 vectors, but how else do I do something like this?

How do I get a "list" of the values that match a given (non trivial condition) ?

Comment: Do you want to store a separate instance in each vector, or store references to the same instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to clone `container_details`:

```
if mount.destination == volume.mountpoint {
   connected_containers.push(container_detail.clone());
}
```

This requires `shiplift::rep::ContainerDetails` to implement `Clone`, which according to [it's docs](https://docs.rs/shiplift/0.4.0/shiplift/rep/struct.ContainerDetails.html#impl-Clone), it does.

---

This does have a few downsides:

1. Double the memory usage (but since it is called Details, I assume that it doesn't use that much memory anyway).
2. Changes to items in `container_details` does not get reflected in the cloned versions.

Having `get_container_details` return `Vec<Rc<ContainerDetails>>` instead, then cloning `container_detail` will only clone a reference.

Comment: "but since it is called Details, I assume that it doesn't use that much memory anyway", funny, I though "but it's called Details, it might be big!" and indeed, it you look at the number of fields in that struct, it's massive.